# Separating numeric chracters in Microsoft Excel 2007

Tags: excel

I am trying to separate multiple characters in an excel spreadsheet. For example, one of the characters in the cell says "55/55", and I would like it to say 55. How would I go about making this change to these characters, as well as other characters that say 2/2 or 100/100.

Thanks

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer about what you want? Try to formulate a statement which both rigorously describes which part of the string is to be extracted and which applies to ALL the strings in question, e.g. "In every case the desired extraction occurs between the very start of the string and the first occurrence of a hyphen in the string".

Comment: Have you tried using the "Text to Columns" feature, specifying that `/` is the delimiter?

Comment: Changing the character on the cells are not allowed by excel.

Comment: What if the cell contains a value such as 11/11, Excel would assume this to be a date - Do you want this to be changed as well?

Comment: Thanks for your help guys! DeanOC I used the / as a delimiter and got the results I wanted! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a split.

```
Sub Break_String()  
Dim WrdArray() As String  
Dim text_string As String  
text_string = "A|B|C|D"  
WrdArray() = Split(text_string, "|")
End Sub
```